# Regular expression for extract key value items

Tags: regex, string, extract

I tried to make a regexp to extract key=value items from string.
The value string may have or not quotes and spaces (type string or numeric).

The string looks like this:

```
VAR key = 'value in string mode';
VAR key = 34;
VAR key=3.3;
VAR key='another value without empty spaces between =';
```

I want extract key and value.

I was develop but is wrong.

```
VAR \@(\w+)\s?\=\s?\'?([\w]+)\'?\;
```

Comment: What do you need, just the data to the right of the `=` sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\w` will *only* match word characters, so neither spaces nor `=` signs. Try this ([demo](http://regexr.com?3438l)):

```
VAR (\w+)\s?=\s?'?([^']+)'?;
```

Answer (score 1):

That one should do the work:

```
^VAR ([^ =]+) ?=[ ']*([^']+)'?;$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get all data inside of the single quotes using look around behavior.

```
(?<=').+?(?=')
```

This will get the key name.

```
(?<=VAR )[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+(?=\=)
```